# How to create Wifip2p group like "Zapya create group" in android?

Tags: android, wifip2p

I want to implement features "create group" and "Search and join" like ones in Zapya by using Wifip2p or wifi in android. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zapya uses hotspot as an underlining technology.
The one who creates the group will create a hotspot and then the one who searches and joins will join that hotspot .

So for you first find on how to create a hotspot in android and then for the other side how to get connected to a wifi ssid based on the schema u decide .

And then once connected try find how to send data between the two connected devices using socket programming .